Which is more expensive between the AWS Partial Upfront and No Upfront payment options?

The correct answer is D, but I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain to me?

Although normally "homework-type" questions are discouraged, since you've already answered the question, the reasoning is as follows:

Spot instances are not really a good solution to the stated problem, as while they are cheap, they are not guaranteed to stay up a year.
On-demand instances are, for Amazon, more expensive. As they can't anticipate perfectly how much capacity they need—at any time customers might need many large servers—they have to keep a lot of server capacity in reserve. This is a risk: having too much unused hardware is a waste of money but having too little results in miffed customers since they can't spin up a new instance.
No upfront costs reserved: when you create a instance, Amazon doesn't know when you'll stop using it. Again, this is a capacity issue and a risk issue. You don't just pay for the instance; included in the price is the cost to Amazon for all the times the hardware isn't used. It's the same for a landlord who rents out apartments: they don't go bankrupt when a lease is up, as they've calculated this risk into their rental fee.
(Partial) upfront costs reserved: when you commit to an instance and pay upfront for X amount of time, Amazon knows how much hardware they need and they know that it'll be paid for. This results in less risk to them and an easily anticipated need for capacity.

Customers paying up-front for an instance is beneficial to Amazon as a business. To encourage customers to use them, some of the cost savings trickle down.
In this case, even more money could be saved by going "all upfront".
